# How to read Python json file?AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load my json file. I am new to MacOS,but that should be the problem. My code
from terminal

import json

```
>>> with open('ticr_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-01-30.json','r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data=json.load(f)
```

I got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'load'
```

The same error happens with json example from Python docs

```
 json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you written everything into one Python interpreter session? It seems to me that you defined the name json before.

Try opening a new Python interpreter or writing your script into a file.